# How to handle objects in typeahead?

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead, twitter-typeahead

For sake of simplicity, let's base this on first simplest example from here:  https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Here is the suggestions array for this example:

```
var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
  'Colorado', 'Connecticut'  etc..
];
```

I want to have objects in this array:

```
var states = [
    {name: 'Alabama', image: 'images/Alabama.jpg', objectId: '123'},
    {name: 'Alaska', image: 'images/Alaska.jpg', objectId: '341'},
    {name: 'Arizona', image: 'images/Arizona.jpg' objectId: '546'},
];
```

and when I will push 'enter' key or click on one of those suggestions, I need to extract this particular object and `.push` it to another array.
How do I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(textbox-id).on('typeahead:selected', function (e, datum) {
    console.log(datum); //object
    console.log(datum.value); // will print Value you have clicked like Alabama is selected then Alabama is printed in the console.
```